# Is there any historical precedent for the European Union quarantining a member state which fails to carry out customs checks on goods

Tags: european-union, trade

The European Union is an organisation which requires its member states:

1. Not to carry out any customs checks on any goods travelling directly from one member state to another member state
2. To carry out customs checks on any goods coming into the member state from a "third state" (i.e. from a country which is not a member of the EU).
3. The checks which a member state is required to carry out under (2) above are (a) checks for conformity of goods to EU regulations (b) collection of tariffs which the EU imposes on the import of third state goods.

Is there any historical precedent where a member state have been, in the opinion of the EU Commission, insufficiently thorough in carrying out the checks in 3 above (perhaps because of a land border which is difficult to police, or because of a cultural sensitivity such as where the third state, of part of it, has historically been part of the member state and is viewed as part of a cultural continuum, or for any other reason, practical or political/cultural) and the EU Commission has ordered the "quarantining" of the member state - i.e. imposing checks on goods travelling from that member state to other member states (i.e. checks which would not normally be allowed under 1 above)?

Comment: That would be a "nuclear option". More common would be try solve it through EU courts first https://www.politico.eu/article/uk-faces-e2-billion-eu-payment-for-china-fraud-trade/ That's because failing to collect import fees or VAT would deprive some other member state of some money, so that's a reason to sue to recover damages.

Comment: Finanvial fines are the first choice like this. https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/mar/08/uk-faces-2bn-fine-over-chinese-imports-scam-say-eu-anti-fraud-investigators

Comment: The EEC dates to 1951. The EU dates to 1992. There isn't a whole lot of history to invoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such a scenario, the Commission's recourse is to launch infringement proceedings. It has done that in the past to force national customs administrations to collect duties or change their interpretation of some rules. On the other hand, I don't see any legal basis for any quarantining or similar measures.

In fact, as far as I can tell, the treaties do not exactly forbid any checks whatsoever (enforcement of the few restrictions that do remain, e.g. on alcohol, does happen). Instead, what's forbidden are charges or quantitative restrictions and the measure you propose would fall under that.

Article 36 TFEU does create an exception “on grounds of public morality,  public policy or public security; the protection of  health and life  of  humans, animals or plants; the protection of national treasures possessing artistic, historic or archaeological value; or the protection of industrial and commercial property.” To the extent that a lack of enforcement would create a health risk, it could conceivably be invoked (presumably by other member states rather than by the Commission).

Note that even when member states are at odds between themselves or with the Commission, they have seldom challenged the core functioning of the single market. Even the developing conflict between the Commission and Poland or Hungary on rule of law or human rights issues doesn't really encroach on that.

Comment: If infringement proceedings are commenced by the Commission is there any procedure to apply for an interim order? For example, if the UK reduced the checks on goods going into Northern Ireland (using Art 16 of the Protocol, say) and the Commission in consequence required Ireland to carry out customs checks at the land border, and if Ireland refused to do so, could the Commission get an immediate order from the CJEU requiring Ireland to do so, or would infringement proceedings against Ireland just proceed in the normal slow way awaiting a court hearing in a couple of years?

Comment: @Nemo I don't think there is any procedure for the Commission to take such measures itself. What it can do instead is ask the CJEU for interim measures. That's what happened recently in two cases concerning Poland (one of them is with the Czech Republic, with no Commission involvement). Poland has been ordered to pay €500k a day until the final judgment on its Turów lignite mine and €1M a day until the final judgment on its supreme court.

Comment: Incidentally, I suspected you might have Ireland in mind and in this case I think we are very far in fiction territory. The Commission is working with Ireland and very keen to appear to be coordinating closely and supporting the country in any way it can. It would also be wary of any suggestion that it is flaming inter-communal violence or threatening the Good Friday agreement. Everybody remembers the blowback after the mere suggestion it could use article 16 over vaccine supplies. It therefore seems *extremely* unlikely to me that the Commission would seek to force Ireland to do anything.

Comment: Politico said in the summer that its sources indicated then that the idea was being considered in Brussels. https://www.politico.eu/article/eu-diplomats-emergency-brexit-plan-ireland-uk-single-market-access/

Comment: @Nemo I read it a bit differently. Politico doesn't say it's coming from the Commission, it doesn't even clearly say whether it's being seriously considered. It's also quoting a diplomat who hadn't heard of the plan, which implies it hasn't been formally discussed in the COREPER, let alone in the Council. In fact, that article seems based mostly on accounts by Irish officials, who accuse France of floating the idea (which it might very well have). As I wrote in my answer, I can see a scenario where other member states would go down that route but I would be surprised if the Commission does.

Comment: It is reported in the Irish Times that a pressure group in the border regions is mounting protests against the possibility of Art 16 being invoked by the UK government. One of their chief concerns is the possibility of a hard border being imposed. Since the UK has stated that it will never implement Checks on the border, and nothing can force it to, presumably the protesters think Brussels might order Ireland to do this http://www.irishtimes.com/news/politics/brexit-protests-to-be-held-along-border-over-britain-s-handling-of-ni-protocol-1.4728217

Comment: @Nemo “Brussels” as in the municipality of Brussels? Which one? I know it's common to use “Brussels” as a metonym for the EU when scoring cheap political points but it's too vague to be useful if you want to discuss relationships between member states and EU institutions.

Comment: Also, some UK politicians occasionnally appear to suggest that unilaterally relinquishing any control on the UK borders is a plausible way to avoid facing the consequences of Brexit but unless you have processes and agreements in place, some checks are a legal and operational necessity. The Irish government certainly never suggested ignoring EU and international law was a substitute for that. It's therefore quite reasonable for people on the border to be concerned about that, quite apart from any effort by the Commission or anyone else to “force” Ireland to do something.

Comment: That's also the way the organisers of the protest and the Irish Times article frame the issue: A hard border would be an inevitable consequence of an absence of agreement (whether the current protocol or something to replace it). You cannot just “wish away” borders between countries, that's exactly the point of the very complex and at times precarious agreements between EU or Schengen countries. It's therefore odd to read this as an opinion or concern about the EU Commission or the Irish government, it would be equally true of any self-respecting sovereign government.

Comment: Appologies for the nomenculture. I tend to use the names of cities as shorthand for the government based there - e.g. Dublin for the Irish government, London for the UK government and Brussels for the **EU Commission** but you are right that much EU Parliament business is conducted in Brussels as well so "Brussels" is ambiguous.

Comment: @Nemo The problem here is also that as we discussed earlier, some pressure is coming from other member states as well. The Commission is the single most important institution but it also has to lean on the Court when it comes to enforcement (it takes two court decisions before any monetary penalty on an interim basis and two more before a final decision). Ultimately, the issue is much broader, it's how to reconcile a border with no physical infrastructure with the law. Even if the EU Commission was doing nothing to enforce it, it would still be a concern for the Irish government.

Comment: I suppose the things which makes it a bit different from other situations are that (a) there has never been any immigration control at the land border (b) Both the Irish  government and the UK government regard it as unthinkable that there could ever be customs checks on the land border (as evidenced by the off-the-scale fury of both governments when the EU Commission tried to impose one in respect of vaccines)     (c) I believe that the Good Friday/Belfast Agreement requires no customs checks - as a consequence of the parity of esteem commitment.

Comment: So I think the situation is unique in that two sovereign states are committed to not doing checks at their common border not just because it makes life easier for everyone but as part of the solemn commitment in the GFA to parity of esteem. I doubt there are any other countries in Europe in this situation.

Comment: Incidentally, the Council is based in Brussels too.

Comment: Good point. Another reason not to use **Brussels** for anything other than sprouts.

Comment: @Nemo The peace process relies on the lack of physical border. In 1998 that was enabled by the shared EU membership. Again, it's not enough to wish customs checks away (whether in the GFA or elsewhere), you need the framework to make that possible and that's precisely the difficulty.

Comment: Another incidental remark: The Commission didn't seriously try to impose customs checks in respect of vaccines, it just flirted with the idea for a few hours and then quickly realised how dangerously stupid this proposition was.

Comment: Did they actually realise of their own accord **before** the diplomatic protests from the Irish government and the UK government?

Comment: Do you think that the Commission really does now understand and take on board the sensitivities in Northern Ireland? I remember listening in disbelief to the televised apology from the Commission after it briefly invoked Article 16. in which the spokesman said "where I come from we have a saying: only the Pope is infallible". Obviously he was just trying to calm things down (like saying "to err is human") but anyone who knew anything about NI (or had any interest in finding out) would not have said that.

Comment: @Nemo Yes, I do think the Commission understands and takes that on board, certainly more than either the British government or member states governments other than Ireland. That said, it's a large organisation and in the rush to deal with the bad publicity some people clearly messed up. Even if that statement is also a very bad way to do it, I also think admitting it was a mistake, even clumsily, and reversing course within hours before taking any concrete steps is significant.

Comment: Importantly for our earlier discussion, I do think that the whole thing makes the Commission *less* likely to strong arm Ireland on the border or make any public comment without checking with the right people.